# How to create a tooltip chart in r using highcharter?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am using `highcharter` library and referred to below link to create an interactive **tooltip chart** in a **bubble chart**

https://jkunst.com/blog/posts/2019-02-04-using-tooltips-in-unexpected-ways/

Plot image:

[image]

Using `gapminder` data as shown in link I was able to reproduce the same but when I use my other data then the tool tip chart doesn't appear.

**Code for my other data:**

libs

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
```

data

```
grouped_cases_df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/grouped_cases.csv")
```

```
tt_base <- grouped_cases_df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Date)) %>% 
  distinct(Country.Region, .keep_all = TRUE)

tt_base
```

```
tt_inner <- grouped_cases_df %>% 
  select(Country.Region, Date, Daily_cases) %>% 
  nest(-Country.Region) %>% 
  mutate(
    data = map(data, mutate_mapping, hcaes(x = Date, y = Daily_cases), drop = TRUE),
    data = map(data, list_parse)
  ) %>% 
  rename(tt_nestdata = data)

tt_inner
```

```
tt_daily <- left_join(tt_base, tt_inner, by = "Country.Region")

tt_daily
```

```
hchart(
  tt_daily,
  "point",
  hcaes(x = Active, y = Confirmed, name = Country.Region,
        size = Daily_cases, group = continent, name = Country.Region) 
) %>% 
  
  hc_yAxis(type = "logarithmic") %>%
  
  hc_tooltip(
  useHTML = TRUE,
  headerFormat = "<b>{point.key}</b>",
  pointFormatter = tooltip_chart(accesor = "tt_nestdata")
  ) %>% 
  
  hc_title(text = "Active Vs Confirmed Cases as of latest Date") %>% 
  hc_subtitle(text = "Size of bubble based on Deaths <br> (ttchart: population growth)")
```

**Issue:** Getting blank tooltip chart for every country.

[image]

I also tried by changing `Country.Region` to `as.factor()` but didn't help. I am not sure whats wrong with this.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to using a date on your x-axis - see [this github issue](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/683)

Comment: thanks @Ben for sharing this link. I guess this is the case. After taking dates as.integer I am able to plot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's needed make two changes:

1. The tooltip data needs to be ready to highcharter. So you need to transform the Date column from text to date then to a numeric value which highcharts can interpret as date:

```
mutate(Date = highcharter::datetime_to_timestamp(lubridate::ymd(Date)))
```

2. Then, in the `hc_opts` argument in the `tooltip_chart` function you need to specify the x Axis treat the values as date.

```
pointFormatter = tooltip_chart(accesor = "tt_nestdata", hc_opts = list(xAxis = list(type = "datetime")))
```

Then:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jbkunst for providing the reasoning & the fix. Your work is amazing !!

Comment: @ViSa sorry for the late response!! Is there a link where your graphic is published?

Comment: this is a very old post  so I am not sure if I published this anywhere. Most probably its not.